# Where does the term "boost" come from for rotation-free transformations?

Tags: general-relativity, terminology

I had never seen rotation free transformations called "boosts" (I think I have it right) before reading some questions here. I'm too old perhaps. I have not found the etymology after some searching, though it sounds like something V.I. Arnold would think up, or jargon from inertial navigation. Anyone know where/how it started or was popularized? (If it is in MTW or Ohanian (old edition) or Weinberg, I promise I'll facepalm)

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily the original source of the term, but the earliest use I can find, occurs in [*Brandeis University Summer Institute in Theoretical Physics*, *1964 Vol. 1*: *Lectures on General Relativity*](http://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/010309536), where on p. 208:

> If we use the term **boost** for a Lorentz transformation from one frame to another parallel to it but with a uniform velocity relative to it, then we can analyze the motion according to the type of transformation as follows: ...

No particular reason as far as etymology is given, though one can guess some plausible analogies. Notably, one can find easily find some uses within a few years after the above on Google Books, including one briefly gives some synonyms for it,

> All of these examples of so-called "pure Lorentz transformations" or "accelerations" or "boosts" (perhaps boost is preferable, as it does not invite misunderstandings) i.e., transformations of the type...

as well as a reason to prefer "boost" (besides simply being less of a mouthful, I suppose).

Comment: Nice bit of research and thanks. I figured a search of papers and colloquia would turn up something but I have let membership lapse in APS and such. Now I have to say I have seen it before and just don't remember. The origin though, is another matter. You have a good candidate here.

Answer (score 1):

In Gravitation, Misner, Thorne and Wheeler first use the term *boost* in box 2.4 starting on page 67. They don't make a fuss of defining the term, so I assume it must have been in common use at the time of publication (1970).

Comment: I see it. It looks more like a verb there compared to the noun in current usage. Maybe it comes from Wheeler's eccentric use of English.